# LEFT JOIN issues

Tags: views

I have a views to display a list of company nodes. The company content type has one boolean field 'field_company_exclude_jobs_home'. This field is to indicate whether this company should be excluded from this views list.

If this field has been checked, then the company should be removed from result. The easy way is to add a filter for this boolean field in views. The thing is by default this field doesn't have value. So the configuration from views filter is not a good solution.

The raw views sql look like this.

```
        SELECT node_field_data.nid AS nid, RAND() AS random_field
        FROM 
        {node_field_data} node_field_data
        LEFT JOIN {node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home} node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home.entity_id AND (node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home.deleted = '0' AND node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
        WHERE (( (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN  ('company')) AND (node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home.field_company_exclude_jobs_home_value <> '1') ))
        ORDER BY random_field ASC
```

What I need is when company doesn't have a row record at table node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home, this company should also returned.

Is this something possible to be done at views sql query alter level? Btw, this can be done at views_pre_render() level to exclude companies already. I'm just curious is this possible for a sql query level.

Answer (score 0):

There's something my colleague has figured out to make this work in a query level.

Add two filters in view ui.

```
WHERE (( (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN  ('company')) AND (node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home.field_company_exclude_jobs_home_value <> '1' or node__field_company_exclude_jobs_home.field_company_exclude_jobs_home_value is '') ))
```

Views ui doesn't have option for filter to allow NULL value. So the second condition "is ''" is made through views_query_alter() level.

```
$query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['value'] = NULL;
$query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['operator'] = 'IS';
```